# An error occurred while reading the Async query

Tags: c#, linq, asynchronous, lambda, entity-framework-core

```cs
try
{
    IEnumerable<Entity> query = await service.QueryableAsNoTracking()
                                        .Where(x => x.IsActive == true)
                                        .ToListAsync();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
}
```

An error occurred while reading the above query. I couldn't find where the error was.

```cs
ex.Message ="query"
```

If I remove try ... catch

This is the error:

```
System.ArgumentException: query  
at DevExpress.Xpo.XPQueryExtensions.ThrowIfNotXPQuery[T](IQueryable`1 query)  
at DevExpress.Xpo.XPQueryExtensions.EnumerateAsync[T](IQueryable`1 query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)  
at DevExpress.Xpo.XPQueryExtensions.ToListAsync[T](IQueryable`1 query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)   
at FIMNextGen.API.ApiControllers.v1.InvoiceController.GetList(GetListRequestModel requestModel) in \Projects\FTS\FIM-NextGen\FIMNextGen\FIMNextGen.API\ApiControllers\v1\InvoiceController.cs:line 80   
at lambda_method(Closure , Object )  
at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutorAwaitable.Awaiter.GetResult()  
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, jectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)  
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker voker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)  
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker voker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)  
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)  
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& Completed)     
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker voker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)  
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task stTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)  
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable ope)  
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger gger)  
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)  
at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)  
at  Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)  
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: What do you man by "error occurred", please? Do you have wrong result (say, 1, 2, 3 when 4, 5, 6 is expected), compile time error (the code doesn't compile), run time exception? In any case, please, provide details. Please, remove `try ... catch` to have the error message if an exception is thrown

Comment: Can you provide what you catch inside that ex? Try Debugging..

Comment: You need to include the full stack trace of the error and any other details of the exception. @Celal Sunnetci

Comment: @DmitryBychenko i removed try...catch

Comment: @RenanFernandes I proceeded in debug mode and found out that the error came from here.

Comment: @Rahatur I edited my question. Can you check again?

Comment: Many people here dislike empty `catch` blocks, and for good reasons. Your question could be improved by simply removing the try/catch around your code. It would be less likely to attract downvotes too.

Comment: According to [this DevExpress support page](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t940595/tolistasync-error), a "ThrowIfNotXPQuery"-exception would be caused by trying to execute a "regular" EF Core query using the **DevExpress version of `ToListAsync`** which is not suitable for that. You need to keep the two worlds separate. It also mentions that replacing **`using DevExpress.Xpo;`** with **`using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;`** should fix the situation. I can not try this myself, which is why I am posting this as a comment.

Comment: @PeterB I replaced it with using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore; and it worked . Thank you

Comment: You will also want to `await` that operation to get the results. If you are not in an `async` method then use the synchronous `.ToList()` not `.ToListAsync()`.